# Android app that lists all installed apps (including system apps)

Tags: android, utility

I want an app that will generate a list of what apps I have installed, in a manner I can save to a file or send in email.

I've looked at an assortment.  I have two at the moment - one freeware, and one open source.  Both list my apps, but *only* those installed via standard add/remove operations.  They do *not* list apps installed as system apps.  Since vendors tend to preinstall some applications as system apps, this is a problem.  (The tablet I'm currently configuring bundles Google Chrome as the default browser, and installs it as a system app.  My app listers don't see it.)

Can anyone recommend an app lister that includes system apps in the list?

Answer (score 1):

I subsequently got a recommendation elsewhere for an app called My Apps (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spencerstudios.applist) that does what I need.  I just need to generate a list of apps on my device that can go to a file and be processed elsewhere.  My Apps both shares to my installed text editor, and can save to my Google Drive.

**@Nino Filiu:** I appreciate the pointers, and will keep them for future reference.  AppBrain and ShareMyApp both do more than needed.  ListMyApps didn't have an open to include system files that I could find.

Answer (score 0):

[**AppBrain**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps) is an Android app available on the PlayStore that lets you export such a list, and so does [**ShareMyApp**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.binarywalllabs.sendapp). [**ListMyApps**](https://f-droid.org/packages/de.onyxbits.listmyapps/) too but it seems to be more oriented for the tech-savvy ones out there.

If you're running an emulator, the `pm list packages` does the job. You can also run it via ADB so that you can extract your actual phone apps from your computer's command line: `adb shell pm list packages > installed_packages.txt`.